# Spivak Calculus ed.3 chapter 3 problem 28(c): Functions and trichotomy law, multiplication/addition closure

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis

Let F be the set of all functions whose domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

**(c)** Show that P10-P12 cannot hold. In other words, show that there is
no collection $P$ of functions in $F$, such that P10-P12 hold for $P$. (It is
sufficient, and will simplify things, to consider only functions which are 0
except at two points $x_0$ and $x_1$.)

**For reference:**

(P10) (Trichotomy law) For every number $a$, one and only one of the
following holds:

1. $a = 0$,
2. $a$ is in the collection $P$,
3. $-a$ is in the collection $P$.

(P11) (Closure under addition) If $a$ and $b$ are in $P$, then $a + b$ is in $P$.

(P12) (Closure under multiplication) If $a$ and $b$ are in $P$, then $a \times b$ is in $P$.

**Spivak's answer**:
Let $f$ and $g$ be the two functions which are 0 except at $x_0$ and  $x_1$, with $f(x_0)=1$, $f(x_1)= 0$ and $g(x_0) = 0$, $g(x_1) = 1$. Neither is $0$, so $f$ or $- f$ would have to be in $P$, and likewise $g$ or $-g$. But $(\pm f)(\pm g) = 0$, which contradicts P12.

**My comment:** Since neither is $0$, then according to (P10) they must be in P. Multiplying $f$ and $g$ is always $0$, including at $x_0$ and $x_1$. But if we follow that logic, how do we prove that P11 also doesn't apply? At $x_0$ and $x_1$, the sum of those would be 1. Spivak's proof only shows that P12 does not apply. Does that suggest trichotomy and closure under addition always apply? The question also posits that (P10) doesn't hold. However, (P10) is assumed to hold to show that (P12) does not hold. Is this an incomplete proof? Or perhaps the question is not asked correctly?

Comment: Should that say `(c) Show that P10-P12 cannot hold.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is just asked poorly: he wants to show that P(10) through P(12) cannot all simultaneously hold, and proves that P(10) and P(12) cannot simultaneously hold, which proves the former statement. In fact, it's possible to have P(10) and P(11) hold: well-order $\mathbb{R}$ using the axiom of choice, then say that $f < g$ if $f(x) < g(x)$ for the first $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$, then let $P$ be the set of all $f$ which are greater than $0$. Of course, you can also have P(11) and P(12) hold by just choosing $P$ in a silly way, like say, $P$ is all functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The contradiction really just lies in P(10) and P(12).